# Using function inside SQL in PHP with special contents

Tags: php, sql, function, select

I have an SQL which i want to check permission on it with a function.

This is my function:

```
function checkPermission($id){
    if($id==1){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So as you can see if this function get number `1` for id its gonna return `1==true`.

And this is my SQL :

```
$connection->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE checkPermission(id)");
```

So in here as you can see this function like this : `checkPermission(id)` the `id` word should send the id of row like when we use this code : `WHERE id=1`

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to call your PHP function using SQL like that. You'll need to select the id from the database, store the result in a PHP variable, and then check that PHP variable using your PHP function.

If you want to run the function in SQL, you'll need to create a stored procedure in the database you are using.